# How to disable: Drag across UITableViewCell selects it

Tags: uitableview

When you drag over a UITableViewCell in a TableView, the cell gets highlighted ("selected"), but didSelectRow... is not called. I wish to disable that selection. How would I do that? Note that setting the selectedStyle for a cell to selectedStyleNone, or something like that, is not what I want. I really want the OS not to select it.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the property your searching for is `BOOL allowsSelection` declared in UITableView. By passing "no" the tableViewCell is not selected when the user touches it. The same is true for `BOOL allowsSelectionDuringEditing`.

I hope that fixes your problem ;)

Comment: This wasn't what I was looking for (I solved it in this thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208865/swiping-a-row-in-a-tableview-clicking-other-selects-swiped)), but I can imagine that you thought I was looking for this! So good answer. :)